# Where to ask for language design review?

Tags: xml, language-agnostic, language-design

I'm designing an xml-base language that is meant to be widely used. I've made an xsd file to define it. I'm in the process to finish the english specification.

My humility tells me that I really need to make it review by language design experts, xml/xsd experts and domain-related experts.

However, the related domain isn't about technical things, it's more about art. So there isn't a lot of programmers with enough experience to help review this language. At least not in my contacts. There are few but I need a lot of eyes to be sure I'm not missing some points.

I'm building a website with a forum to have a place to discuss the design. I also use Google Code hosting to allow submitting issues.

The main problem is to find people that are interested in reviewing languages or interested in both technical and domain-specific things.

What do you suggest to make lot of programmers review a language you designed? Is there some community of language-design expert somewhere? I thought there were about xml-based languages but couldn't find any.

Comment: Why do you believe that your language is better than any of the dozen or so embedded languages already out there?

Comment: That is not related to the question I'm asking but let's talk anyway :) This language was designed because of specific needs in the target domain that is fairly new (well the targeted side of the domain is new anyway) and it is made to solve the problem that there is no general description of some essential structure in the targetted domain. I could have used some kind of graph-description xml-based language, and I looked for them, but they are to "general graph theory" oriented and I (we?) need a more specific solution but still "general" in the scope of the domain.

Comment: In fact, in the beginning of 2009 I talked about something like that on several domain-related forums and thought some people would obviously implement many version of the same idea because it was so obvious to me. 9 months later nobody even oriented research in this direction and it was very strange to me. I thought I was maybe wrong but some experts in the domain pressed me to implement a solution as I was one that was technical enough and had interest in this artistic domain to build something really useful.

Comment: So I had to design this language to have a domain-specific description of some basic essential structure and build tools around it and allow other people to build tools around it. That's the whole story I think :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the question: "How to get it reviewed?"... and I suspect there isn't a good answer. Just asking around through contacts is the only way I know.

But I can take a look at your datamodel if you like. I have done quite a bit of datamodelling for humanities and linguistic content... not sure how well that fits what you're working on.

Comment: You're welcome to take a look and give me any feedback yes :) As the public website isn't complete yet, could you contact me by email (in my profile's website link) so I give you the context and point you to the xsd file? It will be explained publicly soon but it wouldn't be a good idea to ask people to review the xsd file without an explaination first.

Comment: I just re-discovered this entry. You can take a look at my work there: http://artofsequence.org , see the AOSL page, and if you want to look at a more precise definition, there is an xsd file on github: http://github.com/artofsequence/aosl but I'm doing a big upgrade right now (see the feature/AOSL2.0 branch)